# Debug-only Pages with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm currently the solo developer on a React web application, but in January a couple of newbies will be joining me. Because of this, I'm wanting to create live documentation for the application where I can embed components and discuss how they're used and what they're used for.

Rather than exporting all of my JavaScript and CSS files out into a separate project, is there any way I can get webpack to only compile these documentation pages when `NODE_ENV` isn't set to `"production"`?

My current Webpack config looks like this:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: [
          'react',
          'es2015',
          'stage-0'
        ],
        plugins: [
          'react-html-attrs',
          'transform-decorators-legacy',
          'transform-class-properties',
          'babel-polyfill'
        ],
      }
    },
    { 
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: "style!css!autoprefixer!less"
    }
  ]
},
output: {
  path: __dirname + "/dist/",
  filename: "app.min.js"
}
```

I can only assume I need to place some sort of conditional check within the `loaders` section, but this is the first time I've used Webpack and I'm not sure exactly what I'd need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with adding my *documentation* folder to the excluded paths only when NODE_ENV isn't equal to "production":

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
```

```js
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      ...
      exclude: new RegExp(
        'node_modeules|bower_components' +
        (!debug ? path.resolve(__dirname, 'documentation') : "")
      )
    }
  ]
}
```

It's not perfect but it handles my situation nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to install and use [storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/react-storybook)

It creates you a server completely appart from yours. Where you can test, view, and documment all your components in a really easy way.

Check the [Start Guide](https://getstorybook.io/docs/react-storybook/basics/slow-start-guide)

I hope it's what you are looking for